# How to deploy files from s3 to ec2 instance based on S3 event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Actually I am working on a pipeline. So I am having a scenario where I am pushing some artifacts into s3. Now I have wrote a shell script which download the folder and copy each file to its desired location in a wildfly server(Ec2 instance).

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /home/ec2-user/test-temp
cd /home/ec2-user/test-temp
aws s3 cp s3://deploy-artifacts/test-APP test-APP --recursive --region us-east-1
aws s3 cp s3://deploy-artifacts/test-COMMON test-COMMON --recursive --region us-east-1
cd /home/ec2-user/
sudo mkdir -p /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/psg/common
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-COMMON/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml /opt/wildfly/standalone/configuration
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-COMMON/modules/system/layers/base/com/microsoft/* /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/microsoft/
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-COMMON/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-COMMON/modules/system/layers/base/psg/common/* /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/psg/common
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-APP/standalone/deployments/HS.war /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-APP/bin/resource /opt/wildfly/bin/resource
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-APP/modules/system/layers/base/psg/* /opt/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/psg/
sudo cp -rf ./test-temp/test-APP/standalone/deployments/* /opt/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
sudo chown -R wildfly:wildfly /opt/wildfly/
sudo service wildfly start
```

But every time I push new artifacts into s3. I have to go to the server and run this script manually. Is there a way to automate it? I was reading about lamda but after lamda knows the change in s3. where I am gonna define my shell script to run??

Any guidance will be help full.

Comment: Have you tried mounting s3 into ec2 ???

Answer (score 0):

To Trigger the lambda function on file uploading to s3 bucket, for this you have to set the event notification in s3 bucket.

Steps for setting up s3 event notification:-

1- you lambda and s3 bucket should be in the same region

2 - go to Properties tab of s3 bucket

3 - open up the Event and provide values for event types like put or copy

4 - Do specify the Lambda ARN in Send to option.

Now create one lambda function and add the s3 bucket as a trigger option. Just make sure your Lambda IAM policy is properly set.

Comment: It will not work. Because there are multiple deployable in artifact folder inside s3. I need to run the bash script some how or need to design each file with his target location somewhere

Comment: okay so create multiple key paths and event notification respectively and type of file invoking lambda you have to handle on a code basis.

And if you think this will not work then mount s3 bucket to your ec2 instance. for reference https://gist.github.com/karan6190/b711b5e20f61ffbc41828899ff9c8d47